# Replacing corrupt GIT blob

Tags: git, replace, blob, corruption

I have a local GIT repository (no remote backup, I learned my lesson) and there is a corruption. I tracked it down to a blob (file) in one commit. The contents are from another file and it's truncated. The corrupt blob is in two commits. Then there's a newer version of the file.

Could you please suggest how to fix this? I have a few ideas, but my experience with GIT is limited.

1. Fabricate a correct blob using `git hash-object`. But then it will have a different hash. Can I just rename the file?
2. Replace the corrupt blob in the two affected commits by `git replace`. Is there any potential danger with that?
3. The corruption is about 15 commits deep in history. I could reset to the commit before the corruption and manually redo the changes. Perhaps I could then rebase the later commits.

Comment: Path 3 seems easier than going into deep plumbing with blobs, but I might be wrong. It also depends on the number and complexity of recent changes. If they're simple enough, with few (or no) conflicts, I'd say go for the rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's facilities for dealing with detected corrupt objects are ... primitive at best.  The usual way is to go to some backup, but in this case, that option seems to be out.  (But consider local backups, e.g., Time Machine if you have it.)

If the corrupt object (blob in this case) is a *loose* object, and you know the correct *content*, you can remove the bad loose object file and use `git hash-object -w` to create a correct loose object file, which neatly fixes everything.  Presumably, however, you don't know the correct content, which is what led you to this:

> 1. Fabricate a correct blob using git hash-object. But then it will have a different hash.

That is, you make up some content—presumably all-new—and write it to the object store with `git hash-object -w` or `git hash-object -w -t blob` (`-t blob` is the default).  That's all fine as far as it goes, but it doesn't *replace* the *bad* object.

> Can I just rename the file?

No, that won't help: the commit contains a *tree* object, or series of tree objects, that provide the name and then refer to the file's content by blob hash ID.  Those trees will continue to exist.  They refer, by hash ID, to the corrupted blob object: they say, e.g., "when extracting this commit, file `path/to/file` is mode `100644` (`rw-r--r--`) and comes from blob <hash>".  Like all Git objects, once written, they may not be changed—overwriting their data simply produces a corrupt object, i.e., one whose data hash doesn't match the hash name by which Git is told to retrieve the data.

You would therefore need to make up replacement *tree* objects.  These in turn require replacing the commit object, which requires replacing all "downstream" commits (commits that have this commit as any ancestor).  At this point you'd be better off using `git filter-repo` or equivalent.  (Making this work as a *general* way of recovering from corrupted repositories would go a long way to fixing the "primitive at best" that I started off with here, and long-term, that might be the way to go.)

> 2. Replace the corrupt blob in the two affected commits by `git replace`.

This might actually work pretty well, and afterward, you can run `git filter-repo` or the old `git filter-branch` to re-copy the repository to one that lacks a reference to the corrupt blob object.<sup>1</sup>  Combine this, at least conceptually (you wouldn't necessarily need to use `git replace-object` at all) with some sort of repair option to filter-repo and we're getting somewhere in terms of a proper repair facility.

> Is there any potential danger with that?

It leaves the corrupt blob *in* the repository.  This might have some effect on future attempts to repack, so I'd definitely want to use the `git filter-*` tricks.

> 3. The corruption is about 15 commits deep in history. I could reset to the commit before the corruption and manually redo the changes. Perhaps I could then rebase the later commits.

This is essentially a by-hand version of the `git filter-*` method after `git replace`.

Using `git filter-repo` to do it is safer in a sense, as filter-repo uses `git fast-export` and `git fast-import` "under the covers" so as to build an all-new repository from the original input.  This means the newly-built repository—the result of the fast-import—never had any corrupted object introduced into it in the first place.  The real question here is whether `git fast-export` will work *on* the repository that has the corrupted blob, perhaps after using `git replace` or some other trick.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note: I say "can" here as if it's merely a matter of running the commands.  That *might* actually be the case!  But it *might* be that the `git fast-export` operation dies partway through, having stumbled over the corrupt object.  So this may turn out to be a [Small Matter of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming).  In *theory* it should be do-able as we won't need or want the bad object for any purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I appreciate you addressed every bit of my question.

The corrupt blob was a loose object and I was able to recreate it from the previous version and from the "surrounding" changes in the commit. I used ```git hash-object``` and it produced the same hash (I had to delete the corrupt file first). So I didn't have to use ```git replace```. Everything is working, ```git fsck``` shows no errors.

Comment: *I was able to recreate it from the previous version* That's definitely the best way to go, just remove the bad loose-object file and create a good one and *poof* repaired, like [Oculus Reparo](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Oculus_Reparo).